# How can I meet traveling companions in Tokyo's Narita airport?

Tags: japan, airports, travel-companions

My travelling companion and I are flying into Tokyo's Narita airport on separate flights (from two different airlines) that arrive ~50 minutes apart.  We will not have cell phone access and presumably we won't have wi-fi access since the connection at Narita is supposed to be very spotty.  My questions are:

1. Will it be possible to go to the gate of the person who arrives later before going through customs?
2. If not, is there an easily identifiable area after leaving security at which we can meet?

Comment: In my experience Wi-Fi in the Narita waiting areas has been very good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are recommended [meeting places](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_29.html) at Narita.

Terminal 1:

[image]

Terminal 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try hanging around in the pre-customs area for your friend, but you'd need to know the gate, and that it's the same terminal (they have more than one), and be prepared to be ushered along if someone spots you loitering.  One solution is that you could go into the bathrooms that most airports have by the gates and freshen up, using up some of the time.

Failing that, or if you prefer a more reliable method, go through and use one of [Narita Airport's official meeting points](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_29.html) (pictures and locations in link).